# How to disable Amazon shouts in Diablo 2?

Tags: mods, diablo-ii

I'm replaying Diablo2 with Amazon once again and I would like to leave music and SFX sounds, but I want to mute the Amazon, her constant shouts when she shoots are going on my nerves. Does anyone know how to disable character sounds and leave only music/sfx in the game?

EDIT: I'm aware of various MPQ readers available, but I would like to get more specific advice, such as "You need to get tool A, open file B, look for certain rows C and comment/replace them, save file and enjoy the game". Last time when I checked the tools they only could read and export MPQ contents..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked the Phrozen Keep site, but I could not download editing tools from there (WinMPQ to be specific), so I've downloaded latest MPQ Editor from http://zezula.net/en/mpq/download.html (as was suggested in comments) and it was very easy to do the task.

- Backup d2sfx.mpq file
- Open d2sfx.mpq with the editor
- Browse to folder with amazon combat sounds and delete those shouts (I had to delete Valkyrie shouts as well, they are equally annoying)
- Close the tool (somehow it saves changes without asking - be careful!)

Comment: If you just get a list of files like "File0000XXXX.wav", you should select "Open MPQ(s) With Options" and open the MPQ with the appropriate listfile, which you can download from [the same website](http://zezula.net/en/mpq/download.html). Also note that some things appear in `d2sfx.mpq`, some appear in `d2exp.mpq`, some appear in `Patch_D2.mpq`, and some appear in more than one of those places. If you're deleting files and it's not working, make sure you're deleting it from any of the 3 files in which it exists.

Answer (score 9):

You probably need to "mod" Diablo 2. This includes getting a MPQ extractor, getting some silent .WAV files and putting them back into the archive. This will work on Battle.net too (if I recall correctly), as sound effects and music are client-side.

You can get started by visiting the [Phrozen Keep](http://d2mods.com/), the site for Diablo II modding. You're looking for

1. How to read a MPQ archive
2. How to replace files in a MPQ archive.

Comment: I was looking for a more detailed answer, with tool names or maybe a mod link. Perhaps d2patch.mpq which overrides Amazon sounds?

Comment: I'm have not done D2 modding for years, and this is the best answer I could give. I recommend you post in Phrozenkeep's forum there to get more accurate answers.